# I am getting this error [UITextView insertText:] must be used from main thread only - How can I resolve it?

Tags: swift

I get an error on the line of code here: self.TextMessage.insertText(countOfItems)
-[UITextView insertText:] must be used from main thread only

I have been struggling to get this to update the text field with the data.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var TextMessage: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var getUserInput: UITextField!

    var userModel = UserModel()

    @IBAction func PerformAction(_ sender: Any) {

        print("Begin....:" );

        if getUserInput.text == "Ready" {

            TextMessage.text = "OK Player"
            let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value:0)
            let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.run.concurrent", attributes: .concurrent)


            queue.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now(), execute: {
                [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }


                print("1")
                self.userModel.downloadItems()
                semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.now() + 2)
                print("2")
                semaphore.resume()

                let countOfItems = String(self.userModel.users.count)
                print("WE PRINT: " + countOfItems)


                self.TextMessage.insertText(countOfItems)

            })

            print("....END" );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do UI updates on main Thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.TextMessage.insertText(countOfItems)
}
```