# Bug in swift5. UITableView.reloadData() must be used from main thread only, UITableViewController.tableView must be used from main thread only

Tags: swift5

```
import UIKit

class CoursesController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "dataRefreshed") , object: nil, queue: nil) {
            (notification) in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.navigationItem.title =  Model.shared.currentDate
        }
    navigationItem.title =  Model.shared.currentDate
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am getting this error \[UITextView insertText:\] must be used from main thread only - How can I resolve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60171550/i-am-getting-this-error-uitextview-inserttext-must-be-used-from-main-thread-o)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That was always a requirement. Calling reloadData() from a background thread was always a bug in your code - I assume iOS only tells you now.

Make sure not to call reloadData() on a background thread. I have a four line method that you can call as

```
run_on_main_thread {
    // Whatever you want to do on the main thread
}
```